# checkbox limit to 2 is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a simple query which is making some issue.
clicking any two checkbox need to slideDown a div. But when i check two and try to click on 3rd one then it show div and disable further clicking. tried .length >2, tried .length ==2. didn't get proper result.
following is my code

```
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="1"> one <br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="2"> two <br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="3"> three <br>
```

and my script is following

```
$('.single-checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length == '2') {
        $('.mixflav').slideDown();
        $(this).prop('checked', false);         
    } else {
        $('.mixflav').slideUp();
    }           
});
```

kindly advice

Comment: this feddle example is working which is same http://jsfiddle.net/devmount/n9g5hswo/

Comment: add two if conditions to check if you have exactly two inputs are checked or more than two are being checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two checks here, since you want the div to slide down when exactly 2 checkboxes are checked. And when more than two are tried to be checked, just turn the `checked` property for that particular input to false.

```js
$('.single-checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length == 2) {
        $('.mixflav').slideDown();                
    }else if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length > 2){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);    
    }else {
        $('.mixflav').slideUp();
    }           
});
```

```css
.mixflav {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="1"> one <br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="2"> two <br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mixitt" value="3"> three <br>

<div class="mixflav">
test
</div>
```

Comment: first if will slidedown, then if will disable further click else div remain display:none

Comment: it worked like charm... Thank you Kiran, saved my day.

Comment: You are welcome Salman. Glad I could help. Please don't forget to check the correct answer. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

First, `length` is not a string. Use a numeric comparison.

```
if ($('.single-checkbox:checked').length === 2) {
```

Next, you need to split up your conditions for `=== 2` and `> 2`. If you uncheck the box when the value is two, it *becomes 1*.

```
var checkedCount = $('.single-checkbox:checked').length;
if (checkedCount < 2) {
  $('.mixflav').slideUp();
} else if (checkedCount === 2) {
  $('.mixflav').slideDown();
} else {
  $(this).prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: thaks Sam R. one think if i use ===2 it does not allow the 2nd check enable. It immediately stop the check function

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Where you make false your checked item, here you slideDown your div. `.length` already returned a number type object. so you can check it with `>`, `<` or `==` where `===` check equal and also the type (number or string literal).

```js
$('.single-checkbox').on('change', function() {
   if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length > 2) {
       this.checked = false;
       $('.mixflav1').slideDown();
   }else if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length < 2){
       $('.mixflav1').slideUp();
   }
});

$('.single-checkbox2').on('change', function() {
   if($('.single-checkbox2:checked').length > 1) {
       this.checked = false;
       $('.mixflav2').slideDown();
   }else if($('.single-checkbox2:checked').length < 1){
       $('.mixflav2').slideUp();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>First Selection (max 2)</h1>
<input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />Item 1<br />
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />Item 2<br />
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />Item 3<br />
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test" value="4" />Item 4<br />
<div class="mixflav1" style="display:none; ">
this is your desired div 1 
</div>
<hr />
<h1>Second Selection (max 1)</h1>
<input class="single-checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />Item 1<br />
<input class="single-checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />Item 2<br />
<input class="single-checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />Item 3<br />


<div class="mixflav2" style="display:none">
this is your desired div 2 
</div>
```